# Why stderr print later than stdout?

Tags: python, stdout, stderr

`stderr` is no buffer, and `stdout` has buffer.
`stderr` is no reason later than `stdout`

I have tried:

```py
import sys
sys.stdout.write("stdout1 ")
sys.stderr.write("stderr1 ")
sys.stdout.write("stdout2 ")
sys.stderr.write("stderr2 ")
```

run `python test.py`

result:

```
stderr1 stderr2 stdout1 stdout2
```

It works as expected.

---

```py
import sys
sys.stdout.write("stdout1 ")
sys.stderr.write("stderr1 ")
sys.stdout.write("stdout2 ")
sys.stderr.write("stderr2 ")
```

run `python -u test.py`

result:

```
stdout1 stderr1 stdout2 stderr2
```

It works as expected.

---

```py
import sys
sys.stdout.write("stdout1\n")
sys.stderr.write("stderr1\n")
sys.stdout.write("stdout2\n")
sys.stderr.write("stderr2\n")
```

run `python test.py`

result:

```
stdout1
stderr1
stdout2
stderr2
```

It works as expected.

---

```py
import sys
sys.stdout.write("stdout1 ")
sys.stderr.write("stderr1 ")
sys.stdout.write("stdout2 ")
sys.stderr.write("stderr2 ")

print()
string = ""
for i in range(10):
    string = string + str(i) + "\n"
print(string)
```

Actual results:

```
stdout1 stdout2
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

stderr1 stderr2
```

I think it should be:

```
stderr1 stderr2 stdout1 stdout2
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: If you run `python test.py -u`?

Comment: Yes. I have resolved this problem and thanks for your help. However, [Another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266222/why-the-code-print-differently-between-windows-and-linux) troubles me. Do you have free time to help me?

Answer (score 1):

In Python3.x, stderr is line-buffer
In Python2.x, stderr is unbuffered

https://bugs.python.org/issue13597
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stderr